Delta Hedge a FX Barrier Option: P/L losses explanation
I would like some help in understanding what is happening with this delta-hedge of a Knock-Out Put on currencies. This example could be found on pag. 359 of Dynamic Hedging by N. Taleb.
An operator sold a KO Put on USD-FRF 5,60/4,75. Thus, since the Delta of this position is positive, he has to sell, if I am right, the dollars with a forward contract. He delta-hedges at the current spot of 5 USD-FRF and the P/L of the hedged position are the ones in the image below.

Why is there a straight line indicating losses below 4,8? In my opinion, if the barrier is touched, the put knocks out and there should be profits stemming from the short position on the dollar future. Am I wrong?

Why do the P/L increase and are positive above 5? I suspect is something related to the KO put losing in value more than the losses in the forwards contract on dollars. Do I have to take in account the premium received by the operator?


Note: the barrier reported in the text is often different from the one used in chart: it seems an error by the author, he mixes 4,75 and 4,85.

Please, let me know if more details are needed. Thanks for the help.
Edit
Maybe the chart is displaying the negative P/L of the operator: in this case the author's explanations make sense. Do you agree?

With respect to question (1.) If the hedge was a short FX futures, there wouldn't be a call option like payoff, the diagonal line would be flat/horizontal. Although I agree the correct hedge is a short futures because short puts do have positive deltas. Did Taleb write what is the proposed hedge in the text? Or does he just say hedged P&L.

Thanks. Taleb wrote that the option seller is short dollars (line 4 pag. 358). What do you think is happening?

@KaiSqDist maybe is pointing out to the mismatch of the deltas around the barrier? Like, the delta of the sold put is much greater than the quantity bought to hedge with futures at 5USD-FRF so you start losing money? How does it sound?

Honestly not sure. The only way it makes sense to me for the left tail (to be downwards sloping) is a long FX dollars futures.

OK, let's see if someone is willing to give is opinion about this hedge. In the meantime, thank you.
